# is there a way to set an "unknown" variable like "x" inside a sine-equation, and change its value afterwards?

Tags: c++, arduino, fft

I want to write an audio code in c++ for my microcontroller-based synthesizer which should allow me to generate a sampled square wave signal using the Fourier Series equation.

My question in general is: is there a way to set an "unknown" variable like "x" inside a sine-equation, and change its value afterwards?

What do I mean by that:
If you take a look on my code i've written so far you see the following:

```
void SquareWave(int mHarmonics){
    char x;
    for(int k = 0; k <= mHarmonics; k++){
      mFourier += 1/((2*k)+1)*sin(((2*k)+1)*2*M_PI*x/SAMPLES_TOTAL);
    }
    for(x = (int)0; x < SAMPLES_TOTAL; x++){
      mWave[x] = mFourier;   
    } 
  }
```

Inside the first for loop mFourier is summing weighted sinus-signals dependent by the number of Harmonics "mHarmonics". So a note on my keyboard should be setting up the harmonic spectrum automatically.
In this equation I've set x as a character and now we get to the center of my problem because i want to set x as a "unknown" variable which has a value that i want to set afterwards and if x would be an integer it would have some standard value like 0, which would make the whole equation incorrect.

In the bottom loop i want to write this Fourier Series sum inside an array mWave, which will be the resulting output. Is there a possibility to give the sum to mWave[x], where x is a "unknown" multiplier inside the sine signal first, and then change its values afterwards inside the second loop?

Sorry if this is a stupid question, I have not much experience with c++ but I try to learn it by making these stupid mistakes!

Cheers

Comment: You want to take the value of `x` from the second loop? So effectively `mWave[x] = f(k,x)` (where _f_ is the sum in the first loop, just taking its value of `x` from the second loop)?

Comment: Yes that is correct, I want to set x after the sum f (in dependency of k) is processed so that i would get this sum after the first for loop: sin(2πxT) + 1/3 sin(3πxT) + 1/5 sin(5πxT) + ... and after the second loop i want to get this sum: sin(0) + 1/3 sin(0) + 1/5 sin(0) + .... + sin(2π/T) + 1/3 sin(6π/T) + 1/5 sin(10π/T) + .... + sin(3π/T) + 1/3 sin(9π/T) + 1/5 sin(15π/T) + .... with T = SAMPLES_TOTAL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So since I can't use vectors inside Arduino IDE anyhow I've tried the following solution:

```
...

void ComputeBandlimitedSquareWave(int mHarmonics){
    for(int i = 0; i < sample_count; i++){
      mWavetable[i] = ComputeFourierSeriesSquare(x);    
      if (x < sample_count) x++;
     }
  }

  float ComputeFourierSeriesSquare(int x){
    for(int k = 0; k <= mHarmonics; k++){
         mFourier += 1/((2*k)+1)*sin(((2*k)+1)*2*M_PI*x/sample_count);
         return mFourier;
      }
  }

...
```

First I thought this **must** be right a minute ago, but my monitors prove me wrong...
It sounds like a completely messed up sum of signals first, but after about 2 seconds the true characterisic squarewave sound comes through. I try to figure out what I'm overseeing and keep You guys updated if I can isolate that last part coming through my speakers, because it actually has a really decent sound. Only the messy overlays in the beginning are making me desperate right now...

Comment: Glad that you have made progress. I assume that mWavetable[] is a global variable. When a stream of data begins (or sometimes ends) with corrupted data then it may be a variable initialization problem. I am not familiar with Arduino (I know, they are widely used) but to debug this you may have to compile and debug your work on a PC or Linux platform. The debugging tools are available, and you will have a start on writing your unit tests!

Comment: Feel free to vote yourself the answer, as I think you finished your own problem.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! could be the initialization, I'll check it out tomorrow again and insure to make the code run properly somehow, and then i'll give you a final update and hopefully can declare the question solved :)

Comment: Code runs now, the problem was like @natersoz was already suspecting - I didn't initialize the begin of my array with zero! 
Thanks again guys, you've been kind have a good week fellas

Answer (score 1):

@Useless told you what to do, but I am going to try to spell it out for you.

This is how I would do it:

```
#include <vector>

/**
 * Perform a rectangular window in the frequency domain of a time domain square
 * wave. This should be a sync impulse response.
 *
 * @param x              The time domain sample within the period of the signal.
 * @param harmonic_count The number of harmonics to aggregate in the result.
 * @param sample_count   The number of samples across the square wave period.
 *
 * @return double The time domain result of the combined harmonics at point x.
 */
double box_car(unsigned int x,
               unsigned int harmonic_count,
               unsigned int sample_count)
{
    double mFourier = 0.0;
    for (int k = 0; k <= harmonic_count; k++)
    {
        mFourier += 1.0 / ((2 * k) + 1) * sin(((2 * k) + 1) * 2.0 * M_PI * x / sample_count);
    }

    return mFourier;
}

/**
 * Calculate the suqare wave samples across the time domain where the samples
 * are filtered to only include the harmonic_count.
 *
 * @param harmonic_count The number of harmonics to aggregate in the result.
 * @param sample_count   The number of samples across the square wave period.
 *
 * @return std::vector<double>
 */
std::vector<double> box_car_samples(unsigned int harmonic_count,
                                    unsigned int sample_count)
{
    std::vector<double> square_wave;
    for (unsigned int x = 0; x < sample_count; x++)
    {
        double sample = box_car(x, harmonic_count, sample_count);
        square_wave.push_back(sample);
    }

    return square_wave;
}
```

So mWave[x] is returned as a std::vector of doubles (floating point).

The function box_car_samples() is f(k, x) as stated before.

Comment: thanks a lot for taking Your time to help me & for this very understandable commented code, this was a great help so far dude! gonna try it out as soon as I'm at the university in a few hours! I'm gonna report if it works out, thanks man, appreciate it! :)

Comment: So it turns out that I can't use <vector> inside Arduino... 
https://roboticsbackend.com/arduino-stl-library/#std_vector_on_Arduino
I followed every step from these instructions, but I'm unable to compile anything with #include <StandardCplusplus.h> or <vecotr> even though I've chosen the right paths like suggested in the article

Comment: @MaxValentin you shouldn't use vector on an MCU Arduino anyway since memory is very limited. Return values directly in an array